# How catch disabling web push notification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, service-worker, web-push

How can I catch with serviceworker or simple js code, when user who previously allowed the web push notifications for my site disable them? For Firefox and Chrome browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API) to detect the current state of given permissions, as well as listen for changes.

[This article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/permissions-api-for-the-web) has more detail. Here's a relevant code snippet:

```
navigator.permissions.query({name: 'push'}).then(function(status) {
  // Initial permission status is `status.state`

  status.onchange = function() {  
    // Status changed to `this.state`
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    navigator.permissions.query({name:'notifications'}).then(function(status) {
        //alert(status.state); // status.state == { "prompt", "granted", "denied" }
        status.onchange = function() {
            if(this.state=="denied" || this.state=="prompt"){ push_unsubscribe(); }
        };
    });
```

or this:

```
    navigator.permissions.query({name:'push', userVisibleOnly:true}).then(function(status) {
        //alert(status.state); // status.state == { "prompt", "granted", "denied" }
        status.onchange = function() {
            if(this.state=="denied" || this.state=="prompt"){ push_unsubscribe(); }
        };
    });
```

I use it to send information to the server that the user has canceled or disabled notifications. Note that the code is not executed if the user does so in the site settings.